# Como escrever um arquivo __init__ em Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Criei um diretório com 3 módulos. Como abaixo:

```
operacoes
    __init__.py
    soma.py
    media.py
```

No meu arquivo `__init__.py` tenho o seguinte código:

```
from media import *
```

O módulo `soma.py` é usado dentro do `media.py`, então eu terei o `import` dele dentro do media. Mas isso está ok.

Minha dúvida é devido ao erro que está dando no `from <module> import *`, que é o seguinte:

> File "C:\Users\jaqueline\workspace\python3\lib\site-packages\operacoes__init__.py", line 1, in 
>       from media import *
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'media'

Estou fazendo o `import` errado para Python 3? Tem alguma coisa a mais que possa gerar esse erro? Não consigo entender o que está errado.

Answer (score 2):

Até o python 3.3 os arquivos `__init__.py` denotam namespaces para pacotes python. A PEP 420 explicita em seu [abstract](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/#abstract) "namespaces são mecanismos para separar um pacote python em diversos diretórios no disco." E essa PEP veio exatamente para mudar isso, a partir do python 3.3 (PEP citada), os namespaces são implicitos no Python, descartando completamente a necessidade dos arquivos `__init__.py`

Nos exemplos que vc apresenta na pergunta, se media.py precisa usar algo do modulo soma.py, voce pode importar de forma implicta com `*`, ou de forma explicita (mais recomendado) "[Explicito é melhor que implicito](https://wiki.python.org.br/TheZenOfPython)"

No arquivo media.py:

```
# De forma implicita
from .soma import * 

# De forma explícita
from .soma import obj1, obj2 ....
```

Mesmo nas versões anterios que exigem a presença de `__init.py__`, não há necessidade de escrever nada dentro do arquivo.

Comment: Ok. O fato é que estou trabalhando em um pacote que vou usar em outra aplicação, e esse pacote faz a inicialização de algumas coisas no projeto. Dei um exemplo mais simples, como as operações. Eu gostaria de manter o __init__ no meu projeto, o problema é que eu não sei como se escreve o `from ... import ...`. Sempre me da o erro `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<module>'`. Qual é a forma certa de escrever?

Comment: Olá, tive um problema parecido. Verifique duas coisas: i) O nome do diretório tem que ser diferente do nome do arquivo (ex: operacoes/operacoes.py dá erro). ii) O PYTHONPATH tem que está configurado para poder executar na linha de comando.