# Imports no Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, import

Olá! Estou tendo um problema bem recorrente em relação a imports de módulos "customizados" no python 3
eu estou fazendo um projeto de um jogo coisa bem básica mesmo e até agora essa é a estrutura do meu projeto:

```
game/
   __init__.py
   main.py
   classes/
       __init__.py
       player.py
   media/
   scripts/
       __init__.py
       dices.py
```

O problema vem quando no arquivo "player.py" na pasta "classes" para fazer o dano crítico do player ele usa uma função que está na pasta "functions/dices.py"

Se eu tento usar "from scripts import dices" dá o "ImportError: cannot import name 'dices' from 'scripts' (unknown location)"

Se eu usar um import relativo "from ..scripts import dices" dá o "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Já tentei diversas formas inclusive vi respostas noutra discussão a respeito que na PEP 420 os arquivos **init**.py não são mais obrigatórios (até onde entendi do comentário) esse é o link "https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/371871/como-escrever-um-arquivo-init-em-python-3"

Estou sem compreender mais nada! Se puderem me ajudar ficarei muitíssimo grato!

Comment: experimenta colocar: `import ../functions/dice`

Comment: Da error de sintaxe "import ../functions/dice
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: você utiliza `linux` ou ` windows`? se for `windows` acho que trocando `/` por `\` funciona

Comment: Uso windows, no caso é para substituir a barra "/" por dupla crase? "``"?

Comment: Nossa, não percebi que saiu errado o comentario, desculpe, subistitua `/` por \

Comment: Também não foi
import ..\functions\dices
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
O error de sintaxe aponta os dois pontos "..\"

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113663/discussion-between-codigo-de-senior-and-elias-oliveira).

Comment: `from ..scripts import dices`, por que `scripts`, se o nome da pasta é `functions`?

Comment: @EliasOliveira veja se a resposta dessa questão te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/427965/import-em-diretorios-diferentes-em-python3/427966#427966

Comment: @Woss foi error de digitação (aqui na discussão) o nome da pasta é scripts, mals pelo vacilo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido! Consegui identificar o problema procurando o caminho que o interpretador estava fazendo, basta importar o módulo sys e usar o método sys.path que lista todos os diretórios que o interpretador irá buscar. Ao fazer isso não encontrei o diretório dos scripts apenas a pasta raíz do projeto. A solução pra isso é bem simples:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('D:\...\...\game v3 (stable)\scripts')
```

Onde os '...' representam o caminho para a pasta com os scripts, ao fazer isso no main.py tive acesso ao diretório dos scripts

Comment: Atenção todos que forem usar isso, isso solucionou o meu problema na máquina local, mas em ambientes de produção, ou em outras máquinas não vai funcionar já que está se referindo ao caminho absoluto em referencia a minha máquina, a melhor alternativa é investir bastante tempo para pensar na estrutura do projeto.

Answer (score 0):

[De acordo com a documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports), quando você quer *importar* algum arquivo local, basta colocar: `import nomeDoArquivo`, mas quando ele está em uma pasta diferente da local, o `python` utiliza o `.` envés da / ou .

Com isso seu `import` ficaria assim:

```py
from scripts.dices import *

# seu código aqui em baixo
```

Ou

```py
import scripts.dices
```